# Save Core Data Attribute from a For Loop - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsdictionary

I have the following For loop which loops through a Core Data entity and then checks to see if  a NSString called keyString matches the attribute. If it does match I then want to set that attribute on the entity to another NSString called value :

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [exhibitor entity];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [entity attributesByName];
    for (NSString *attribute in attributes) {
        if ([keyString isEqualToString:attribute]) {
            exhibitor.attribute = value; //This bit is wrong.
        }
    }
```

The problem is with the line exhibitor.attribute = value. I need to somehow reference the attribute object on exhibitor. Can anyone assist ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MOs are key value compatible. so:

`[exhibitor setValue:value forKey:attribute];`